# PC to Rasberry Pi Serial Communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial, communication, level-shifting

Im trying to communicate to my pc using my raspberry pi using a software called Docklight. I'm using a serial cable (that i ripped apart) and my breadboard as shown below.

Now, you can also see I also I have a level converter. I thought this would solve the problem becuase i was converting the logic level from the PC to the rasberry pi. But when i was using this software it would display ''. I made sure that in my code my baud rate is 9600, no pairtity and a bytesize is 8.

I was wondering if theres another way I could connect the raspberry pi to my pc using this serial wire.

I didn't make this clear but in my question I was only talking about the TX from the raspberry pi to the RX of the Pc. I hope my new layout makes more sense.

[image: New setup]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Since you say your software settings are correct, there's a high chance something is wrong with your hardware. Could you show a schematic of your circuit? I.e. what logic converter do you use, how is it all connected?

Comment: i added a schematic

Comment: Normal USB UART cable adapters can work with 3.3V UART signals - just connect the white or yellow wire to your raspi's TX pin. Here's some random cable: https://megaeshop.pk/pl2303-usb-to-uart-ttl-cable-module-4p-4-pin-rs232-converter.html

Comment: @Neamus - Unfortunately your circuit is unclear. (a) The photo of the breadboard (especially at an angle and far away) is not enough to easily understand and confirm the connections around the level converter. (b) On the breadboard, you have another IC (DIP 14 pin?) which you didn't mention in the text. I can guess what function it has (but you should explain, of course), however it does not seem to have enough connections - I can only see 3 connections, but there should be at least 4 (Vcc, Vss, signal in, signal out). It looks suspiciously as if the dangling yellow wire should be connected.

Comment: [continued] It will be easier for readers to understand your design, if you edit your question to show better quality, more close-up photos, perpendicular to the breadboard, and also explain (and supply the schematic for) *all* the design, including that DIP IC you haven't yet mentioned so far. Thanks and good luck :-)

Comment: @Neamus - Thanks for updating the photo with a much better one. My guess about the DIP IC was wrong, so I'm glad you clarified and removed it. Why are you treating the PC serial connection as if it is a 5V signal? You have not described any of that. This is part of what I wanted, when I asked for the schematic of "*all* the design". Please show (or describe) the type of PC serial port connector and your analysis of the signal type there. Also show (or describe) anything between that connector and the end of the cable which we see on your photo, going into the level converter. Thanks.

Comment: [continued] Do you have an oscilloscope (or, less useful at this stage, do you have a logic analyser) and experience using it? Do you have a multimeter (DMM)?

Comment: @PkP true, but the raspberry pi pins are not 5V tolerant. At the pi's RX pin, there should be at least a voltage divider when connecting it to a 5V UART module.

Comment: @sweber 1) I didn't tell him to connect anything to the pi's RX pin. Just the white wire to the TX pin. (Ground is obviously needed) 2) most USB UART cables are 3 volts, some are 1.8 volts. I've never personally seen a 5 volt one, although I'm sure such cables exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the wrong type of level converter for a PC serial port.

RS232 to logic level requires a bipolar *inverting* converter.  Bipolar in the sense that it uses both positive and negative voltages in the 12 to 15 volt range.

Your pictures shows a unipolar *non-inverting* device intended for inter-logic connections such as I2C.

To adapt the pi to RS232, get a module based on something like a max3232.

Or just get an ft232 or cp2102 based USB to 3.3v serial converter.